# Define own WM message for Message Pump in C++

Tags: c++, window, message

How do I define my own WM (like WM_CLOSE, etc) message that can be handled by the message pump in C++?

If that is even possible.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what you are using the message for. [This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644930%28VS.85%29.aspx) shows a breakdown of the "address space" for Win32 messages.

`WM_USER` is **not** the correct solution in the general case. `WM_USER` messages "can be defined and used by an application to send messages within a private window class. **These values cannot be used to define messages that are meaningful throughout an application, because some predefined window classes already define values in this range**."

You are better off assigning a message ID that is in the `WM_APP` range.

`RegisterWindowMessage` is useful if you want to have the system assign you a message ID at runtime. "All applications that register the same string can use the associated message number for exchanging messages," so you can use `RegisterWindowMessage` when you need to use a custom message for simple inter-process communication.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can simply define your own messages as a constant greater than WM_USER:

```
#define WM_MY_MESSAGE (WM_USER + 1000)
```

Then you can use the normal ON_COMMAND/ON_NOTIFY macros.

The problem with user defined messages like this is that other programs can use the same constant as you.  And you may get a message from someone else for the wrong thing.

To get past this problem you would use registered messages with [RegisterWindowMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644947(VS.85).aspx).

There's a good rundown on [user defined messages/registered messages](http://www.ucancode.net/Visual_C_MFC_Example/RegisterWindowMessage-WM_USER--VC-Example.htm) here.

Comment: Note of course that other programs are not supposed to be sending you messages withing the `WM_USER-0x7FFF` range. Heck, they're not even supposed to be sent _within_ a program. For that you have `WM_APP-0xBFFF range`. The WM_USER is internal to a window class, not a program.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "RegisterWindowMessage" to create new unique messages.

from MSDN : "The RegisterWindowMessage function defines a new window message that is guaranteed to be unique throughout the system. The message value can be used when sending or posting messages."